# Is there anything that can be done to improve reliability on Apple Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Right now it seems that Apples Push notification Server is "Fire and forget". Surely there is some mechanism to improve the reliability, as other apps seem to have a higher rate of success (90%) wheras we are experiencing more of a 50%.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's servers for uses I have seen, have been extremely reliable (along the 99.9% lines).

If you are having delivery issues, the real question is - how are you sending the push notifications to Apple's servers?  It's easy for the server on your end to drop requests, or not be able to handle throughput - also possible with third party services that send notifications for you.

Also possible is messing up push provisioning on the client side so registration for tokens is not happening when you think it is, for instance new code is required for iOS8 to properly register for push notifications - older code will fail silently when compiled using the newer XCode.

Comment: We built our PNS with C# and run it on a Windows 2008 Server, using WCF. PNS Registration is definitely not an issue as we log it once the device has received confirmation that its been done.

Comment: I would check to make 100% sure you are not dropping desired pushes from the stream you are sending to Apple...  In almost all of the cases I've seen of failed push delivery that has been the issue.